# How do I ignore an alert using selenium + chrome webdriver + python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to ignore the alert raised by Chrome Webdriver:
[Alert Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVP6v.png)

I am trying using: `browser.switch_to.alert.accept` but it is not working.

I already set up the option as:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
```

But I believe the alert is not a notification object.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
```

Answer (score 3):

While your original post mentioned that you couldn't get the alert code to work, the accepted answer didn't work for me. Looking at the [documentation](http://allselenium.info/python-selenium-handle-alerts-prompts-confirmation-popups/), I successfully used:

```
 alert = browser.switch_to.alert
 alert.accept()
```

Answer (score 1):

This way helped me to handle the alert boxes and save the screenshot of the URL.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String alertText = alert.getText();
System.out.println("ERROR: (ALERT BOX DETECTED) - ALERT MSG : " + alertText);
alert.accept();
File outputFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String imageDetails = "C:\\Images";
File screenShot = new File(imageDetails).getAbsoluteFile();
FileUtils.copyFile(outputFile, screenShot);
System.out.println("Screenshot saved: {}" + imageDetails);
driver.close();
```